# Creating DEM from Point Data using QGIS?

Tags: dem, point, qgis-2

My boss gave me a small 3D-point-shapefile and asked me to make an DEM from it, which I should put together with an older DEM of the same site, which was made with Surfer.

I created a raster-layer from the shapefile and used the contour-tool to create level-contours. Unfortunately they seem to be lines instead of polygons. When I use the tool line-to-polygon some of the levels disappear. I am sure there is a way to create a DEM from point-data, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I use QGIS Valmiera.

Answer (score 12):

A DEM (digital elevation model) is a raster and not contour lines or polylines. If the point data is a systematic grid of points (equal spacing) then it is as simple as converting straight to raster using a rasterize tool. In QGIS you can use "Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to raster)".

However, if the points are irregular then the becomes a interpolation problem. There are many options available. The stock QGIS "Raster > Interpolation > Interpolation" tool only has TIN and IDW available. I would not really recommend either of these methods but they may be adequate for your needs. Through the QGIS toolbox [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) (need to install) provides Kriging and Spline interpolation. There are also several very robust options in GRASS GIS (also avaliable in the QGIS toolbox).

GRASS interpolation options:

"r.surf.nnbathy" - Natural_neighbor

"v.surf.bspline" - B-splines

"v.surf.rst" and "v.vol.rst" - regularized splines with tension

"v.krige" - Kriging (GRASS 7+)

Often one try's a few methods and then selects a model based on RMSE (Root Mean Squared Error) or residual error to evaluate model fit.