# How to derive a hydrologically correct DEM from point shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I used grass gis v.surf.rst function to interpolate a surface using vector points. But it is very difficult to find a optimum parameters to be used. I am still unable to develop a accurate terrain

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, as you did not tell, you want to create a raster form the points. A similar question about this can be found here:
[How can I create a DEM from Point Data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118243/how-can-i-create-an-dem-from-point-data)
Second, I think there are tools in grass, callable from qgis, to make a depressionless dem, like the r.fill.dir tool.
Other GIS-people tend to use saga gis functions, as described here: 
http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_preprocessor_4.html.
For myself I always used arcgis functions from hydrology toolbox.

Comment: I used grass v.surf.rst function to interpolate raster from points.But it is difficult to find optimum parameters to be used and i am still unable to develop an accurate terrain