# Creating DEM from mesh?

Tags: dem

I have a mesh ( with points and triangles that define it), and I will need to create a DEM model out of it ( in geotiff format if possible for space consideration, if not, then in ASCII grid format). I need the DEM for watershed and catchment delineation purpose.

Instead of using existing software like ArcGIS, I want to write my code to do it ( in C++ or C#), so that I can later integrate them into my own GIS software. is there anything in GDAL or other open source source code libraries that do this well? Or do I have to write from scratch?

PS:

1. there are a lot of posts like [Seeking tool to generate Mesh from DTM?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/121561/1261) on how to do it the other way round, ie: from DEM grid points to mesh, but they are not what I want.
2. I have a similar question as [Getting grid points for DEM purpose that is bounded by surveyor points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304685/1261) on how to get DEM grid points from point clouds, but that is fundamentally different from this one. I don't need the mesh interpolation part for this question, as I *already* have the mesh.
3. I can always create the bounding box for the mesh, loop through each grid points, get the `z`, and then construct the grid, but this is crude and can be slow. I'm unsure whether there is a faster way of doing it?

Comment: I managed to interpolate rasters from csv file (but technically there is no difference between these and a set of vertices extracted from the mesh) using Python Scipy, which has nice interpolation modules. If you are interested I can share the code later.

Comment: @dmh126 , The CSV file is the point cloud, or already in mesh format? Anyway in both cases I will be interested to see the code, regardless of language

Comment: Point cloud. Just X,Y,Z.

Comment: @dmh126 , in that case, can you post the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304685/1261)?

Comment: Okay, I posted here and also pasted it to your other question. Just close one of them because it's a duplicate. If you got any question I can answer them tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something similar to Python Scipy will do the job. I can share one of my scripts which uses Scipy to interpolate a raster image from vertices ans saves it as a geotiff file.

Extracting vertices from the mesh should be easy, I just load a csv file to x, y, z variables where each one is an array:

```
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate as inp
from osgeo import gdal , osr

x, y, z = numpy.loadtxt ( ’ points.csvv ’ , skiprows =1 ,
delimiter = " , " , unpack = True )
```

Next some useful statistics:

```
xmin = min ( x )
xmax = max ( x )
ymin = min ( y )
ymax = max ( y )

# number of pixels with 1m resolution
nx = (int(xmax - xmin + 1))
ny = (int(ymax - ymin + 1))
```

Now a grid, which is also a bounding box, it is represented by nx pixels between xmin and xmax and the same for Y direction:

```
xi = numpy.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
yi = numpy.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xi, yi = numpy.meshgrid(xi, yi)
```

And the most important function, in Scipy it is just simple like that but if you can't find any library for C++ or C# you can always write it from scratch, some of these interpolations are quite simple (ex. inverse distance weighting).

```
# used method: nearest neighbour; there are also cubic and something else
zi = inp.griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')
```

`zi` variable represents the corresponding Z values so all we have to do is write it to a file (geotiff in this case).

```
rows,cols = numpy.shape(zi)
sizex = (xmax-xmin)/float(cols)
sizey = (ymax-ymin)/float(rows)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_raster = driver.Create('raster.tif', rows, cols, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(zi)

# georeference
georeference = (xmin, sizex, 0, ymin, 0, sizey) 
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(georeference)
srs = osr.SpatialReference().ImportFromEPSG(2180)
output_raster.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
```

And thats all, the example raster.tif file created by this script (zmin red, zmax green):
[image]

Here are the docs, you can check out these methods, everything is described:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/