# Using Python for interpolate data points with Scipy (open for other solutions as well)

Tags: python, raster, point, interpolation, scipy

I have dataframe which contains coordinates and measurements, something similar to this (this is fake):

```
id   lat          long        mes
0     -14.1309    -52.4561    0.1
1     -14.1312    -52.5327    0.05
2     -14.1308    -52.3324    0.07
3     -14.1302    -52.3323    0.03
2     -14.1302    -52.3312    0.01
```

I want to interpolate this data points. I want my final raster to have size that I have already defined (3586, 2284). I have tried to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315583/interpolation-points-data-into-2-d-shapefile-with-matplotlib) post :

```
xt,yt = df['long'].values, df['lat'].values
zt =  df['mes'].values

from scipy.interpolate import griddata
CONC = griddata((xt,yt), zt, method='cubic')
```

But then it says I'm missing the `xi` argument:

> TypeError: griddata() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xi'

My end goal is to interpolate these points to get raster with the given dimensions (3586, 2284) with the correct coordinates. I'm also open to use other libraries, but seems like scipy is the best one.

**Edit:** I have tried  @snowman2 solution, however it return empty raster:

```
geo_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=points3d,
    resolution=(-0.1, 0.1),
    rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_points_griddata, method="cubic"),
)
geo_grid.rio.to_raster("path_to_raster.tif")
```

[image]

Then I have tried also using xarray to interpolate , I could plot my data but could not interpolate:

```
Latitude=points3d['Latitude'].values
Longitude=points3d['Longitude'].values
data=points3d['Data'].values

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays=[Latitude,Longitude], names=["Latitude","Longitude"])
s = pd.Series(data=data, index=idx)
s
# use from_series method
da = xr.DataArray.from_series(s)
da
```

[image]

this can be plotted:
[image]

But when it is interpolated, I get only nan:

```
dsi = da.interp(Latitude=Latitude, Longitude=Longitude,method='linear')
```

[image]

Comment: Suggest you read the help file for this [tool](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)?

Comment: @Hornbydd yes, just not sure how to define the xi, I know  what is the size e of the result raster- e.g the shape of the new array, I know the values, but I don't understand the xi, what does it mean point which to interpolate the data? is confusing me because I have already xt,xy , and I don't understand from the example in the original post what is it and how it was determined.

Comment: `xi` is the coordinates at which you want to sample, so that would be the coordinates of your target raster's cell centers.  You could create these with `np.meshgrid()`, [see the examples here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: @mikewatt thank you for your respond. There is still soemthing I don't understand -  xi should be the coordinates of the final raster? of the full raster? i'm confused as in the post I based on, the write defined xx and yy with np.linspace(110, 120, 40) (and different numbrs for yy)  and i'm not sure where it comes from. I have tried to put my xt and yt but that priduces array with no shape. soemthing here still confusing me.

Comment: @mikewatt just to add, I used mashgrid like this : xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xt, yt, sparse=False, indexing='ij')  and then put it in the interpolation. However, when I plot it with imshow seems like it didn't take into consideration the coordinates

Comment: `xt` and `yt` aren't what you want to feed into `meshgrid`, that only goes into `griddata`. 
 You want to feed in the row and column coordinates for your target raster, created with `linspace` or `arange`.  Essentially you'll use one of those to step along each dimension of your target raster using the cell size as the interval.  (That means it's also not ideal to be using geographic coordinates for this, so consider projecting to something more appropriate.) Then after running those row/col coords through `meshgrid`, you'll end up with an array containing the center coordinate of every cell

Comment: @mikewatt so tif I understand you, the meshgrid is the destination of the interpolation, and in linspace I create the corodinates of the rows and columns (what does it mean? coordinate of first cell of each column?). I have tried to do this with the data of the original post, calculating the size of the bounding box uses with interval of 40 (135245,100728), which is weird as the write used 110, 120 and 25,45 for the linspace. Could you maybe provide an example for your explaination ?

Comment: Check this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/305894/28714

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/corteva/geocube/

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "lat": [-14.1309, -14.1312, -14.1308, -14.1302, -14.1302],
    "long": [-52.4561, -52.5327, -52.3324, -52.3323, -52.3312],
    "mes": [0.1, 0.05, 0.07, 0.03, 0.01],
})
```

Step 1: Convert to geodataframe

https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html

```py
import geopandas

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df['long'], df['lat']), crs="EPSG:4326",
)
```

Step 2: Convert to raster

- https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/geocube.html#make-geocube
- https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/rasterize_point_data.html

```py
from functools import partial

from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from geocube.rasterize import rasterize_points_griddata

geo_grid_cubic = make_geocube(
    gdf,
    measurements=["mes"],
    resolution=(-0.00001, 0.001),
    rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_points_griddata, method="cubic"),
)
geo_grid_cubic.mes.plot.imshow()
```

[image: Cubic interpolation]

You can also fill in the missing data:

```py
geo_grid_cubic = make_geocube(
    gdf,
    measurements=["mes"],
    resolution=(-0.00001, 0.001),
    rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_points_griddata, method="cubic"),
    interpolate_na_method="nearest",
)
```

[image: Cubic interpolation with nearest fill]

And you can use linear interpolation as well:

```py
geo_grid_linear = make_geocube(
    gdf,
    measurements=["mes"],
    resolution=(-0.00001, 0.001),
    rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_points_griddata, method="linear"),
    interpolate_na_method="nearest",
)
```

[image: Linear interpolation with nearest fill]
With radial interpolation:

```py
geo_radial = make_geocube(
    gdf,
    measurements=["mes"],
    resolution=(-0.00001, 0.001),
    rasterize_function=rasterize_points_radial,
)
```

[image: radial interpolation]
Default griddata interpolation:

```py
geo_griddata = make_geocube(
    gdf,
    measurements=["mes"],
    resolution=(-0.00001, 0.001),
    rasterize_function=rasterize_points_griddata,
)
```

[image: griddata interpolation]

Comment: I have tried your solution but got blank raster (see the original post, the edit section).

Comment: I would try making the resolution smaller. Maybe 0.001?

Comment: I updated the response with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

How about [QGIS 3](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and its [IDW Interpolation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#qgisidwinterpolation) tool?

[image]

Step-by-step instructions:

1. Convert the text data into a vector layer (use `Add Delimited Text Layer` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> key combination).
2. [Optional] Convert a degree coordinate system (such as WGS 84) to a meter coordinate system (such as UTM 30N) with the [Reproject layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#reproject-layer)  tool.
3. Use the [IDW Interpolation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html#qgisidwinterpolation) tool to interpolate the data with the desired parameters (see picture above).

P.S. Your example data lies almost on the same line, so you can't use it as an example. Add more points to make it look more like a square.

Comment: I did not want to use QGIS, the whole point was for me to try solve it outside QGIS , but it's indeed good solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for another solution I have found : using the [Scikit GStat library](https://scikit-gstat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) . This solution worked for me the best.
It allowed me to use Kriking interpolation  in convinient wat with my data.

example for how I run kriging with this library:

```
df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

#this is function from sentinel hub that I used but you can get the bbox with other libraries
bbox_size,bbox,bbox_coords_wgs84=get_bbox_from_shape(res_intersect,10)


totalPointsArray = np.zeros([df.shape[0],3])

for index, point in pdf.iterrows():
     pointArray = np.array([point.geometry.coords.xy[0][0],point.geometry.coords.xy[1][0],point['Data']])
        totalPointsArray[index] = pointArray
        
x=totalPointsArray[:,0]
y=totalPointsArray[:,1]
z=totalPointsArray[:,2]     
    
cords_bbox=bbox.get_polygon()  
    
xmin = cords_bbox[0][0]
xmax = cords_bbox[2][0]
ymin = cords_bbox[2][1]
ymax = cords_bbox[0][1]
    
# number of pixels with 1m resolution
nx = (int(xmax - xmin + bbox_size[0]))
ny = (int(ymax - ymin + bbox_size[1]))
    
xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)     
    

    

data=pd.DataFrame(zip(x,y,z))
data.columns=['x','y','z'] 

V = Variogram(data[['x', 'y']].values, data.z.values, normalize=False, maxlag=60, n_lags=15)
fig = V.plot(show=False)
print('Sample variance: %.2f   Variogram sill: %.2f' % (data.z.var(), V.describe()['sill']))
    
ok = OrdinaryKriging(V, min_points=5, max_points=15, mode='exact')
      
field = ok.transform(xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()).reshape(xi.shape)
s2 = ok.sigma.reshape(xi.shape)

    
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))    
plt.imshow(s2)
plt.title('Error')
plt.show()
    
    
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.imshow(field)
plt.title('Kriging Interpolation')
    
plt.show()
```

Using Kriging produced better interpolation in this case and I found this library very nice and easy to use. They also ahve very nice and detailed tutorials in their documentation.