# Wrong transform after interpolating points

Tags: python, coordinate-system, interpolation, affine-transformation, scipy

Following [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408665/using-python-for-interpolate-data-points-with-scipy-open-for-other-solutions-as/409257#409257), I'ms trugglig wwith interpolation and projection of set of points. I have used griddata in order to interpolate, and seems like interpolation hapenns, however, the results look tilted ,like transform is wrong, but I couldn't find the mistake in the calculation.

This is the original set of points:

[image]

This is how I do the interpolation:

```
points3d = gpd.read_file('shape/clay.shp')
points3d = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    points3d, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(points3d.Longitude, points3d.Latitude))
print('number of points:{}'.format(len(points3d)))
points3d = points3d.set_crs(epsg=4326)


totalPointsArray = np.zeros([points3d.shape[0],3])

for index, point in points3d.iterrows():
    pointArray = np.array([point.geometry.coords.xy[0][0],point.geometry.coords.xy[1][0],point['Data']])
    totalPointsArray[index] = pointArray

x=totalPointsArray[:,0]
y=totalPointsArray[:,1]
z=totalPointsArray[:,2]

xmin = min(x)
xmax = max(x)
ymin = min(y)
ymax = max(y)

# number of pixels with 1m resolution
nx = (int(xmax - xmin + bbox_size[0]))
ny = (int(ymax - ymin + bbox_size[1]))


xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi) 

zi = inp.griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='linear')
plt.imshow(zi)
```

The result seems to be tilted:
[image]

**I couldn't find the error I have in the calculation. My end goal is to have interpolation aligned to the points and not "tilted".**

[image]

Comment: it looks like you've switched the direction of the Y axis - probably an origin mismatch between geography (lower left) and graphics (upper left)

Comment: @IanTurton true, that fixed it. thanks!

Comment: can you post and accept an answer to help future users

Comment: @IanTurton  yes, I thought you may wanted to get the points for this, but I can post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the problem was mismatch between geography (lower left) and graphics (upper left).
I have gotten my bounding box coordinates (in this case, I have used sentinel-hub bbox , hence I have used the get_polygon function:

```
bbox.get_polygon()
```

and then based on the coordinates of the bounding box I have carefully selected the uper left instead of the lower left coordinates of the y-axis.